# How is named the "length" of range from a random variable?

Tags: random-variables

I have a random variable, lets name it A. Then the range of this variable can be calculated as follows:

```
r(A) = (min(A),max(A));
```

Given this conditions what would be the name of the "length" of that range.

Here I understand as "length" the following:

```
l(A) = |r(A)[1]-r(A)[2]| = max(A)-min(A);
```

So, how this would be called or how can I express this in a mathematical way?

Comment: How exactly do you define *length of the range ?*

Comment: Ass I said I'm defining "length" of the range by _max(A)-min(A)_. I know that's not a good word. Thats why I'm asking.

Comment: The difference between max and min value is called "range", see [measures of spread](https://statistics.laerd.com/statistical-guides/measures-of-spread-range-quartiles.php).

Comment: In fact what you are calling the "range" is rather the *support* of the random variable, see https://www.statlect.com/glossary/support-of-a-random-variable

Comment: Ty @Conifold all sites I've visited expresed the range as support. Didn't knew the difference.